# Cannot resolve method 'with(Context)'

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-glide, withcontext

I am using the latest version of android studio this my adapter program  this was used in my previous projects glide version: 4.14.2 the context is showing the following error Cannot resolve method 'with(Context)'.

```
package com.example.mystorein.adapters;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.mystorein.R;
import com.example.mystorein.modal.Restaurent;
import com.google.api.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RestaurentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   Context context;
   ArrayList<Restaurent> list;

   public RestaurentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Restaurent> list) {
       this.context = context;
       this.list = list;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public RestaurentAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       return new      ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.toprated_near_item,parent,false));
      }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position)).into(holder.Img);
       holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
       holder.delTime.setText(list.get(position).getTime());

    }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return list.size();
   }

   public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       ImageView Img;
       TextView name, delTime;

       public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           Img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Img);
           name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
          delTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delTime);

       }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know the reason for this error and any suggestions to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The error `Cannot resolve method 'with(Context)'` occurs because the wrong `Context` class has been imported. The code has imported `com.google.api.Context` instead of `android.content.Context`.

To fix this error, you need to replace the incorrect import statement:

```java
import com.google.api.Context;
```

with the correct import statement:

```java
import android.content.Context;
```